# Need to make program paralleling Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in java using arrays

Tags: algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

We were assigned to make a java program which paralleled Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. I have tried several times in every which way i know of, but haven't been able to get it right. Im supposed to use fill arrays with prime numbers less than the number that was imputed. Here is the code I have, Can someone please help me in double checking the program and/or figuring out why I am getting this error? Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Arrays;



public class Lab6st
{
static int MAX = 100;
static int i;
static int k;
static int intArray;
static int isPrime;

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    System.out.println("\nLAB12 100 Point Version");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean primes[] = new boolean[MAX];
    computePrimes(primes);
    displayPrimes(primes);
    Arrays.fill(primes,true);
}

public static void computePrimes(boolean primes[])
{
    System.out.println("\nCOMPUTING PRIME NUMBERS");
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++);
    {
        for (i=1; i < MAX; i++ );
        for (k=2; k<i; k++){
            int n = i%k;
            if (n==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i==k);
        {
            primes[i] = true;
        }       
    }
}

public static void displayPrimes(boolean primes[])
{
    System.out.println("\n\nPRIMES BETWEEN 1 AND "+ primes.length);
    for (int isPrime = 0; isPrime < MAX; isPrime++);
        if (primes[isPrime] == true);
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(primes));              
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes; it's a poor implementation of trial division (the modulo operator gives it away). My [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) *Programming with Prime Numbers* describes the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in detail, discusses the very common error that you made, and includes this implementation in Java:

```
public static LinkedList sieve(int n)
{
    BitSet b = new BitSet(n);
    LinkedList ps = new LinkedList();

    b.set(0,n);

    for (int p=2; p<n; p++)
    {
        if (b.get(p))
        {
            ps.add(p);
            for (int i=p+p; i<n; i+=p)
            {
                b.clear(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return ps;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note. Since you are trying to make this fast, it might pay to make the list ps into an `ArrayList` instead of a `LinkedList`. Despite the fact that an ArrayList may have to be resized, it still usually outperforms a LinkedList. You might want to benchmark it though. Even better would be to reserve sufficient space for the ArrayList in places where that can be done.

Comment: Actually, I was going for clarity of code, not speed. It's easy to make this run *much* faster. See my essay referenced above for an optimized Sieve of Eratosthenes.